# automatically redirects to index page instead of desired page

Tags: php, validation, laravel, redirect

I have a **taskController controller** in my laravel application.Inside my resource folder i have have three pages under **resource/views/taksController/**

> 1.index.blade
>
> 2.store.blade
>
> 3.create.blade..

in my **create.blad**e i have a form which on submit will go through a validation and if succeeded i want it to be redirected to **store.blade** ,otherwise it will redirect to **create.blade** again to fill up the form again.But here in my program ,on success it doesn't redirect me to **store.blade** file, rather it redirect me to index.blade.Why is this happening?How i can solve this?

**i am using laravel 5.2**

In my route.php i added the controller like

```
 Route::resource('taskController','taskController');
```

in taskController the validation logic inside controller  is like the following:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    return View::make('taskController.index');
}


public function create()
{
    //
    return View::make('taskController.create');
}


public function store(Request $request)
{

    $rules = array(

    'email'    => 'required|email',     // required and must be unique in the ducks table
    'comment'  => 'required',
    'agree'    => 'required|accepted'           // required and has to match the password field
  );
 $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
  if ($validator->fails()) {

    // get the error messages from the validator
       $messages = $validator->messages();
       echo 'bal';
    // redirect our user back to the form with the errors from the validator
   return Redirect::route('taskController.create'); 


   }else{
    return Redirect::route('taskController.store');

   }
}
```

Comment: where you have loaded your view? like index, store, create?

Comment: didn't get your question...they are inside resource/views/taskController/ directory

Comment: share your create function code

Comment: added my full controller page to the post.please check it out

Comment: it looks perfect. still its not working as you desired?

Comment: i wanted to use redirect ::route instead of view::make.. because ?Redirect::route not redirecting me to disered page..it redirect me to index.blade instead of store.blade..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL used for the `index` route and the `store` route are the same. The difference is the HTTP verb that is used on that URL. GET requests to the URL will take you to the `index`, whereas POST requests to the URL will take you to the `store`.

In your `store()` method, when you `return Redirect::route('taskController.store');`, the `route()` method converts the parameter to the URL, and then makes a GET request to it. This is why you are redirected to `index`.

Generally, your `store`, `update`, and `destroy` routes don't have views associated with them. They are meant to perform an action and then redirect to the route that contains the view.

For example, the general workflow for creating a new resource is:

1. `create` route shows create view which has the form,
2. form POSTs to `store` route,
3. `store` route attempts to create new resource,
4. if validation fails, `store` route redirects back to `create` route with errors,
5. if resource is created successfully, `store` route redirects to the `show` route, with the id of the newly created resource.

The workflow for editing a resource is similar:

1. `edit` route shows edit view which has the form,
2. form PUTs to `update` route,
3. `update` route attempts to edit the resource,
4. if validation fails, `update` route redirects back to `edit` route with errors,
5. if resource is modified successfully, `update` route redirects to the `show` route, with the id of the modified resource.

Comment: that means if i use Route::to('taskController.route'),, it will send me to taskController/index.blade.php directory ? So do i have to use View::make() to redirect me to a desired location all the time?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have this:

```
public function index(){

 return view('taksController.index');

}

public function create(){

 return view('taksController.create');

}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $rules = array(

    'email'    => 'required|email',     // required and must be unique in the ducks table
    'comment'  => 'required',
    'agree'    => 'required|accepted'           // required and has to match the password field
  );
 $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
  if ($validator->fails()) {

    // get the error messages from the validator
       $messages = $validator->messages();
       //echo 'bal';
    // redirect our user back to the form with the errors from the validator
   return Redirect::route('taskController.create'); 


   }else{
    return view('taksController.store');// redirects me to index.blade instead of store.blade

   }
}
```

Comment: my page is quite similar... what's your point? why i should i use view instead of redirect?

Comment: if you redirect to store again then it won't able to get those Request array data. so, it could be the issue.. not sure